# Recaptcha not shown by colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

i am using colorbox jquery for show registeration form in popup box.

i used the following script initiate popup

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

       $(".ajax").colorbox({width:"30%"});

</script>
```

in popup i called the registration form with Recaptcha. i can get all form fields in popupbox but not recaptcha .

i getting recptcha code is place of recaptcha in ajax form     with noscript

```
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LdxveQSAAAAADjToPLUgHY6IRxJgreFWwwOF47H" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <br/>
    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
```

[image: Popup box without recaptcha]

Actual registration form without ajax

[image: actual regiestration form without ajax]

Answer (score 0):

Recaptcha in popup can be done by the following code

```
<head>

<!-- ... your HTML  content ... -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>

  <!-- Wrapping the Recaptcha create method in a javascript function -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function showRecaptcha(element) {
       Recaptcha.create("your_public_key", element, {
         theme: "red",
         callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field});
     }
  </script>

  <!-- ... more of your HTML  content ... -->

</head>

<body>

  <!-- ... your HTML <body> content ... -->

  <div id="recaptcha_div"></div>

  <input type="button" value="Show reCAPTCHA" onclick="showRecaptcha('recaptcha_div');"></input>

 <!-- ... more of your HTML  content ... -->

<body>
```

[Google's details  information about this problem](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#AJAX)

Result [image]